# How to do deal with an evolutionary design of a web-site database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-design, c#-4.0, orm

I am about to start my first project on an ASP.NET MVC 3 web-site. This site will have data storage and I am wondering what's the best way to deal with the evolutionary design of the database behind the web-site - after the site launches, it will be extended and it will keep on growning thus database refactoring will be an issue. What's the best way to deal with this "problem"? I was thinking of using an ORM like NHibernate or Entity Framework, but neither of them support evolutionary database design.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for migrations support for .NET primarily?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313/net-migrations-engine

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033/database-migration-library-for-net

[.NET migrations: Setup and migrate multiple databases at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252911/net-migrations-setup-and-migrate-multiple-databases-at-runtime)

I can assure you that developers are doing evolutionary database design with both NHibernate and Entity Framework, so it's entirely possible.  Maybe you want a highly tooled, automated process though?

Comment: We are using [RoundhousE](http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/) in all our .net applications to upgrade the database schema together with the update of the application.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've checked them out quickly, I will do a more thorough "investigation" soon!